# how can I make my blurred image into a link (HTML)

Tags: html, css, hyperlink

I made my image blurred when you hover over it but every time I try to make the image clickable where it redirects to a new link, the image disappears on Chrome. How can I fix this?
This is the code I have right now for my blurred image:

```
<div class="textWithBlurredBg2">
         <img src="https://taylorsdigigracelim.files.wordpress.com/2014/04/week-4-practical-ex-1.jpg"> </a>
            <h2>travel</h2>
        </div>
```

**(that's my code in HTML)**

```
.textWithBlurredBg2 {
    width: 300px;
    height: 200px;
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 4px;
    position: relative;
    transform: translate(370px, 200px);
}
.textWithBlurredBg2 img {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    border-radius: 4px;
    transition: .3s;
}
.textWithBlurredBg2:hover img{
    filter: blur(2px) brightness(90%);
    box-shadow: 0 0 9px #DA70D6;
}
.textWithBlurredBg2 :not(img) {
    position: absolute;
    top: 30%;
    z-index: 1;
    color: #fff;
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;
}
```

**(That's my code in CSS)**

Comment: Shouldn't the image disappear when you redirect your site to a new address? Any demo in jsFiddle or StackOverflow would be helpful.

Comment: We're missing the link tag in your html code. There is only a closing tag. Can you provide the full example?